# Different behaviour of a nested query on 2 different SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, nested, pointer-aliasing

The following query returns two different results on two instances of SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
create table a(id int)

insert into a(id)
values(1)

insert into a(id)
values(2)

select 
   id,
   (select count(dbo.a.id) from dbo.a where dbo.a.id = "a"."id")
from a 
where a.id = 1
```

First machine gives

```
id          
----------- -----------
1           2
```

Second machine gives

```
id          
----------- -----------
1           1
```

We know how to fix this problem by using an explicit alias in the subquery. But because we use constructions like this a lot, it would be an immense work to do. So we would like to understand the problem.

Is there maybe an option in SQL Server to control this behaviour?

2013/07/22:

DBCC USEROPTIONS;SELECT @@VERSION; gives

```
Set Option                    Value
----------------------------- ----------------
textsize                      2147483647
language                      Deutsch
dateformat                    dmy
datefirst                     1
lock_timeout                  -1
quoted_identifier             SET
arithabort                    SET
ansi_null_dflt_on             SET
ansi_warnings                 SET
ansi_padding                  SET
ansi_nulls                    SET
concat_null_yields_null       SET
isolation level               read committed
------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)
        Jun 17 2011 00:57:23
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

        Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
```

and

```
Set Option                    Value
----------------------------- ----------------
textsize                      2147483647
language                      Deutsch
dateformat                    dmy
datefirst                     1
lock_timeout                  -1
quoted_identifier             SET
arithabort                    SET
ansi_null_dflt_on             SET
ansi_warnings                 SET
ansi_padding                  SET
ansi_nulls                    SET
concat_null_yields_null       SET
isolation level               read committed
------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   
        Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
        Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 <X64> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

For the first server the query work how we want it.

2013/07/24

It seems not to depend on the server but on the databases.

Server:

```
Set Option                   Value
---------------------------- ----------------------------------------------
textsize                     2147483647
language                     Deutsch
dateformat                   dmy
datefirst                    1
lock_timeout                 -1
quoted_identifier            SET
arithabort                   SET
ansi_null_dflt_on            SET
ansi_warnings                SET
ansi_padding                 SET
ansi_nulls                   SET
concat_null_yields_null      SET
isolation level              read committed

(13 Zeile(n) betroffen)

Die DBCC-Ausführung wurde abgeschlossen. Falls DBCC Fehlermeldungen ausgegeben hat, wenden Sie sich an den Systemadministrator.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86) 
Jun 17 2011 00:57:23 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)


(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)
```

Following query:

```
create table a(id int)
insert into a(id)
values(1)
insert into a(id)
values(2)
select * from a
select 
   id,
   (select count(dbo.a.id) from dbo.a where dbo.a.id = "a"."id")
from a 
where a.id = 1
drop table a
SELECT USER_NAME() AS CurrentUser;
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() AS CurrentSchema;
```

First database gives:

```
id
-----------
1
2

(2 Zeile(n) betroffen)

id          
----------- -----------
1           2

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)

CurrentUser
--------------------------
dbo

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)

CurrentSchema
--------------------------
dbo

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)
```

Second database gives:

```
id
-----------
1
2

(2 Zeile(n) betroffen)

id          
----------- -----------
1           1

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)

CurrentUser
-----------------------
dbo

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)

CurrentSchema
-----------------------
dbo

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)
```

Comment: Run `DBCC USEROPTIONS;SELECT @@VERSION;` on both instances and publish the results.

Comment: This ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298674/en-us)) is the expected behavior in such cases (sub-queries). Try to run this query `SELECT * FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.database_id=DB_ID()` on both databases and compare the results. Please tell me if you find something.

Comment: Maybe [this] will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation could be that those `a` tables have diff. rows.

Otherwise, I can't reproduce the problem. A query that references objects without a explicit schema (ex. `SELECT * FROM A`) can give you diff. results on the same *server* if

1) That query is executed by diff. users.

2) The users are mapped to diff. schemas (ex. dbo and dbo2).

3) There are two(or more) tables/objects with the same name in diff. schemas (ex: `dbo.A` and `dbo2.A`).

Run this script in SSMS with `SQLCMD mode` selected (menu: Query > SQLCMD mode):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE DATABASE Test;
GO
USE Test;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.A(ID INT);
INSERT INTO dbo.A(ID) VALUES (1);
GO

CREATE SCHEMA dbo2;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo2.A(ID INT);
INSERT INTO dbo2.A(ID) VALUES (1),(2);
GO
-- Test database has two tables [A] with diff. schema (dbo, dbo2)

USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN login_test_1 WITH PASSWORD='pas$w0Rd', DEFAULT_DATABASE=Test;
GO
CREATE LOGIN login_test_2 WITH PASSWORD='pas$w0Rd', DEFAULT_DATABASE=Test;
GO
USE Test;
GO
-- This user is mapped to schema [dbo]
CREATE USER user_test_1 FOR LOGIN login_test_1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;  
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.A TO user_test_1;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo2.A TO user_test_1;
GO
-- This user is mapped to schema [dbo2] (!)
CREATE USER user_test_2 FOR LOGIN login_test_2 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo2;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.A TO user_test_2;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo2.A TO user_test_2;
GO

-- Test login_test_1
:CONNECT (local)\SQL2008R2 -U login_test_1 -P pas$w0Rd
SELECT USER_NAME() AS CurrentUser;
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() AS CurrentSchema;
SELECT  *
FROM    A;
GO

-- Test login_test_2
:CONNECT (local)\SQL2008R2 -U login_test_2 -P pas$w0Rd
SELECT USER_NAME() AS CurrentUser;
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() AS CurrentSchema;
SELECT  *
FROM    A;
GO
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Results:

```
Connecting to (local)\SQL2008R2 as login_test_1...
CurrentUser
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_test_1
CurrentSchema
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbo
ID
-----------
1
Disconnecting connection from (local)\SQL2008R2 as login_test_1...

Connecting to (local)\SQL2008R2 as login_test_2...
CurrentUser
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_test_2
CurrentSchema
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbo2
ID
-----------
1
2
Disconnecting connection from (local)\SQL2008R2 as login_test_2...
```

In this case, login_test_1 (dbo) gets **1** row but login_test_2 (dbo2) gets **2** rows.

Cleanup script:

```
/*
DROP DATABASE Test;
DROP LOGIN login_test_1;
DROP LOGIN login_test_2;
GO
*/
```